EGR switch off and reprogrammation only
I would like to close my EGR valve so that only "fresh" air is in the comubstion chamber.
I read my ecu file (EDC15c2 on Puegeot 307 2.0 HDi 90hp) and I located the three bits "EGR Swtich with/without". They are by default equal to 001 so I will put 000 instead and write the new ecu file using MPPS.
Do I need to do any physical change to any component of my engine after this modification ? Are there any points I should pay attention ?

The EGR is not only has an emissions function, but also will keep the engine from burning too hot. You might want to consider the consequences for what your plans are.

In UK vehicles over 3 years old must pass an emissions test annually. Disabling the EGR valve may cause a fail.
